# Does split() method in java create new String in String constant pool?

Tags: java, arrays, string

If I split a String using space as a delimiter, does it create new String in String constant pool for each unique String?

```
String s = "This is a simple Java Program";
for (String val: s.split(" ")){
     System.out.println(val);
}
```

Will new Strings be created for "This", "is", "a", "simple", "Java", "Program"?

Comment: as they don´t represent literals, no

Comment: No, it doesnt..But it creates new Strings on the heap

Comment: No, it doesn't. Neither the JavaDoc, nor the source code are suggesting that.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. This is a well-posed question.

Comment: I agree @Bathsheba. Thank you for the comments

Comment: @Bathsheba "doesn't show any research effort" ... do you have more questions?

Comment: @Tom I tried looking for this answer at a lot of places. I was not satisfied with the answers. I thought it's better to clarify the questions or doubts regarding a particular topic and discussion always results in a better outcome.

Comment: "Will new Strings be created for "This", "is", "a", "simple", "Java", "Program"?" Yes. But this isn't the same as asking if those strings will be added to the string constant pool.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did a lot of research ... and you completely ignored the JavaDoc and the source code?

Comment: @Tom I didn't go through JavaDoc or the Source code.

Comment: No. It creates sub-strings, which share the char array with the original string. So for an OO language the overhead is minimal.

Comment: @JoopEggen are you sure about that? [It looks like](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#201) the char array isn't shared (similar behaviour [way back when](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#233)).

Comment: @AndyTurner you are totally right. Once upon a time it was different - I hope.

Comment: @JoopEggen in any case, new *String* instances are created.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't: `s.split(" ")` is **not** a *compile-time evaluable constant expression*; the returned array of strings is computed at *run-time*.

This still remains the case even if the separated strings are in the pool.

Comment: Thank you. Will substr create a new String in String constant pool?

Comment: No it doesn't, once again `substr` is not evaluated at *compile-time*.

Comment: Perhaps mention how you know it's not evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for this knowledgeable question.
split(limit) returns the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression at run time.
So it doesn't create new string in constant pool.